# Ability to close my own questions as duplicates

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, questions, duplicate-questions

I recently asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609762/mvn-installinstall-file-custom-finalname) and was shown [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400369/how-to-use-artifactid-with-different-filename-in-dependencies) that I hadn't found myself, that handles the same problem.

I then voted to close my own question as a duplicate and was surprised that it still needed 4 other peoples time to do the closing.

Therefore I would like to request the ability for everyone to be able to close owns own question as duplicate without the need of other people.

As [Cupcake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/456814/cupcake) pointed out, there is already [this request on M.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172002/163250). It basically covers the same topic and is far better written.

Comment: Related [meta.se] question: [Grant the OP a binding close as duplicate vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172002/163250).

Comment: Why not simply delete your question? Why keep another duplicate around instead?

Comment: @l4mpi If I didn't found that other answer than other people might have the same problem. The problem descriptions are sufficiently different that its not given that just because you find one means you find the other one. (Thats the reason for the "close as dup" process as a whole. Duplicate markings are signposts.)

Comment: Then I'd say four other people will have to agree with you that the question is sufficiently good to keep around as a signpost; otherwise you could "lock" your question by closing as a duplicate which means it won't be auto-deleted and people can't close it for other reasons...

Comment: @l4mpi One can still flag the question or vote to delete it, even if its closed. You can't lock a question this way. Also if its a dup why close it for another reason? Why bother reading it anyway EXCEPT when you happen to have the same problem? There is no need to only have good questions as signposts - even to the contrary, the bad questions will be a signposts for future bad questioners with the same problem.

Comment: Both flagging and deletion are "harder" tasks than simply closing a question, deletion requires 10k users, flagging requires a mod interaction. And I could think of many reasons to close a question even if a suitable duplicate exists on the site; the most common one is probably that the duplicate is from a few years back but the question would now be considered off-topic. Not saying that all hell would break loose if your suggestion were implemented, but there are many aspects to consider (e.g. educating new Users about this) and I don't see an issue with the current community-driven process.

Comment: @l4mpi The issue is that its time consuming. As you can see in the backlog of Questions here on M.SO there are more and more people fed up with the amount of bad questions (especially duplicates) here. There are various requests to reduce the amount of interaction required to close the bad questions because of this situation.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but the issue is mostly with bad questions from new OPs. If OP cares enough to look for a duplicate himself and vote to close his own question as a duplicate, I'd guess his question is probably fine to begin with. In case of the low-level PHP questions or the 10k java NPE questions I'm pretty sure that at least 95% of OPs don't even care about what happens to their question after they have obtained enough information to fix their problem; so I doubt this proposal would have a big impact for these cases.

Comment: @l4mpi Yeah, I think so. But I want a feature for users that do care in the hope that making the site better for them will increase their numbers :)

Comment: I just came across this issue.  I did some searching and didn't fin the answer, so I posted my question.  let it stew for the weekend and came back, no answers.  did some more searching and found an answer on SO that worked for me.  vtc'd my question to mark it as a duplicate

Comment: my argument for doing this is that English is fickle, there are many different ways to ask the same question, and while the algorithms are decent at finding related questions, they aren't 100%.

Comment: @DForck42 be sure to upvote the linked M-SE request.