# I can vote to close my own question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I posted [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267454/tag-stats-dont-get-updated-when-tags-in-questions-are-edited) and later (after it has been answered) someone else voted to close it as duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267348/tags-gave-x-non-wiki-answers-with-a-total-score-of-y-not-accurate). He's right, it's a duplicate so I voted myself to close it (supposing a vote on my own question should close it immediately). With my surprise my own vote (on my own question) still counts "1".

Then there is something I don't understand: if I can vote to close my own question why my votes doesn't close it immediately?

(reminder: questions with an answer cannot be deleted by owner, I don't think it's dup of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254647/ability-to-close-my-own-questions-as-duplicates) or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172002/163250)) because actually there isn't an answer there (answer to question "Why?").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no special provision for the owner of the post, no. Your vote carries the same weight as any other close vote.

Closing a post removes the ability for (more) people to answer, letting the owner of the question insta-close can be open to abuse. Letting the owner *vote* like everyone else is then the next best option.

Comment: I didn't think about possible abuses of "insta-close" but yes...with many thousands users there may also be a new Macchiavelli...

Comment: I also see absolutely no way this prevents abuse since one can close it with an extra click automatically.
If one wanted to prevent abuse, one should not allow the user to close themselves without someone suggesting.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer: that only applies to duplicate closing, not to closing in general, and *that option didn't exist* when I wrote this answer.