# I'm not ready for this amount of power

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I just got access to the Review Queues. I've been using Stack Overflow for a few years, but I'm not sure I know what would be the best thing for the site.

I feel as though I have been given the powers of a moderator (of sorts) without any training whatsoever.

Are there any good guides that would help me better use this newfound power?

Comment: Try using it a bit and you'll realize that the "power" you have isn't really that impressive.

Comment: Yes, read the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues). / Probably there is a meta question for that already, search for it.

Comment: In all seriousness, you can't singlehandedly screw up. (Almost) everything that gets reviewed needs to go through multiple reviewers. So a good way to gauge yourself is to look at how other people are reviewing the same things that you look at.

Comment: `1` If you're not sure you can always skip a question/answer. `2` After a few years, you must have seen a lot of highly upvoted and downvoted question/answer, and probably be able to differentiate them.

Comment: [Interesting read](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=43027541#43027541).

Comment: For First Posts and Late Answers queues, this should help: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts

Comment: @Mysticial With regards to first posts, I know from experience how much of an impact the reviewers had. I never understood why I felt like I was being downvoted and ignored; now I understand how the mechanisms work and why that might be. I don't want to contribute to that, but I also feel like I don't understand why some great questions are downvoted and closed when they make sense and seem to have reasonable answers and fit what the site says it wants.

Comment: Actually... those queues don't allow you to do anything special to those Q/A, just normal votes and comments. It just draws more attention to those posts.

Comment: @user202729 That's plenty enough to hurt people's feelings and make them feel confused or  bad about the site and their work and us.

Comment: @Bryan thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. Sorry I didn't find it on my own.

Comment: You VTC your own post? Then why didn't [Community] hammer it?

Comment: [Ok no problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168745/what-happens-when-i-vote-my-own-post-for-closing). [On Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267458/i-can-vote-to-close-my-own-question). Still, sometimes [Community] does hammer it.

Comment: @user202729 There's no point in having a larger discussion/talk here if the answer is already someplace else :) What do you mean by [Community] hammering it?

Comment: [This](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43039921#43039921).